# Which tense should these sentences be?

Tags: grammar, verbs, differences, tenses

> Whatever has happened recently even just for a second ago that **was** the past

And

> Whatever has happened recently even just for a second ago that **is** the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you read the term ‘that’ - or more accurately, whether you treat the thing *that* references as [a use or a mention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction).

If you treat it as a *use*, you are referring to something in the past, so ‘was’ would be appropriate.

If you treat it as a *mention*, you’re talking about the concept (or definition). Then since that concept is still extant, *is* would be appropriate.

Either way, you should place some kind of punctuation before the word *that*. A dash would work; a comma is also serviceable there.